# HTML hyperlink is not operning in a new tab

Tags: hyperlink, tabs

```
echo "<td align = 'center'><a href='edit/edit_rrdalert.php?id=".$alertid . 
    "&title=".$inst_title."&cat=".$categories["$cat"]."'target='_blank'>edit </a>";
```

I want to open the link in a new tab as  edit/edit_rrdalert.php?id.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be your call to decide whether the link should open in a new tab or a new window, since ultimately this choice should be done by the settings of the user's browser. Some people like tabs, some other like new windows.

Using _blank will tell the browser to use a new tab/window, depending on the user's browser configuration, and also depending on how they click on the link (middle click, ctrl+click, normal click).

but if you wish to do it set the target attribute of your  element to "_tab"

EDIT: It works, however W3Schools says there is no such target attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp